# how to get count of the repeated values xml element in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Element count]

In above figure the element Chandru  is repeated as two times.

so i have to count the repeated element.

But i don't know to get count of repeated element.

please help me.

Here the code what i wrote

```
public XML_3()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("D:/student_2.xml");

        XmlNodeList student_list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Student");

        foreach (XmlNode node in student_list)
        {
            XmlElement student = (XmlElement)node;

            string sname = student.GetElementsByTagName("Chandru")[0].InnerText;                

            string fname = student.GetElementsByTagName("FName")[0].InnerText;

            string id = student.GetElementsByTagName("Chandru")[0].Attributes["ID"].InnerText;

            Window.Content = sname + fname + id;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var count = student.GetElementsByTagName("Chandru").Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier using LINQ to XML and X-Classes:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("D:/student_2.xml");
var results = (from s in doc.Root.Elements()
              group s by s.Name into g
              select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
```

this will give you a list of elements with two properties each: `Name` and `Count`. If you want to receive only that names, which occurred more than once you can add `where g.Count() > 1` between `group` and `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a C# programmer, but hence, I can give you the algorithm then you can try to apply it on your program.

Define an array of struct, the struct must have two fields: ElmntName and NbOccurance.

```
struct Elmnt
{ String ElmntName;
  Int NbOccurance;
} MyElement;
```

Then each element you pass thorugh, pass through your array, if the elementwas not found, save it as new element with NbOccurance=0;
Else, if it was found increment the number of occursnces.
At the end of reading your xml, you will get a list containing the names of the elements and their occurances.